# jQuery Mobile 1.4 and Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery-mobile, microsoft-edge

I am working on RWD application which was developed using jQuery Mobile 1.3. We have decided to upgrade jQuery Mobile from version 1.3 to 1.4. Our concern is how well jQuery Mobile works in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10. The jQuery site does not mention anything about Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile is developed around standards and common conventions, as is Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, and other browsers. You should not run into any serious issue when using any of these modern browsers.

There are currently 271 [open issues](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues) on GitHub for jQuery Mobile. A cursory search didn't reveal anything serious with Microsoft Edge. If you do happen to run into issues, please [file them on Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/new), and share them here so that we can help you identify temporary work-arounds.

Internet Explorer versions 8 through 11 received an **A** in jQuery Mobile's [Graded Browser Support](http://jquerymobile.com/browser-support/1.4/). Considering the fact that Microsoft Edge has received thousands of bug fixes more than Internet Explorer 11, I would say it's safe to assume you should have a wonderful experience using jQuery Mobile along with Microsoft Edge.